# How to get the Namespace of static void main() using Reflection?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I want to get the namespace of `static void main()` of the application from a library.

I know that you can use Reflection to get the entry assembly. Is there a method or a way in which I can get the namespace of the `static void main()` method?

Comment: `Assembly.EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace`? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().EntryPoint`. Take a look at [EntryPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_EntryPoint).

Comment: @CodeCaster I looked for this "c# get namespace of static main" on google. Will try what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the namespace of the class where the `Main` method of your executable is defined:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace;
```

[Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) gets you the assembly where the entry point is defined, the `EntryPoint` property gives you a `MethodInfo` that represents the `Main` method itself. You can then get the namespace from the `Type` returned from the `DeclaringType` property.

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. Explain what it does.

Comment: It does exaclty what the OP asks for, i.e. it returns the namespace of the `Main` method of the entry assembly.

Comment: That's not the point. My point is that answers containing _"Try this [code block]"_ aren't the high-quality answers we strive for. It doesn't hurt to type a little bit of explanation or add links to documentation.